# unable to set other specified column as primary key instead of Id column to table using entity framework code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, code-first

I have two table 
`Product` and `Order`

```
public class Product
{
 string name;
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[Key]
public Guid  productId { get; set; } // i want this to be primary key instead default Id
}

public class Order
{
 string name;
 [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[Key]
public Guid  orderId { get; set; } // i want this to be primary key instead default Id and also want to add productId inside this table as foreign key
}
```

I have used following code to use code first.

DatabaseContext.cs

```
  class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }
```

Program.cs

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DatabaseContext>());

            using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
            {
                context.Product.Add(new Product() {  Name = "mytest" });
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Database Created!!!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

getting exception

```
Additional information: Unable to determine composite primary key ordering for type '.Customer'. Use the ColumnAttribute (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386388) or the HasKey method (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386387) to specify an order for composite primary keys.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF supports only properties so you should change your fields to properties. When you do that use {class Name} + Id as the property name and it will be picked up as the key property by convention. Alternatively you can use the `[Key]` attribute on a property to let EF know it should be the key property. You can find more about EF attributes [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Key).

Comment: From your code it does not seem that you are using composite keys because you have just one property. I don't know what your intention is - do you want to use composite keys or not. Read the article I provided a link to - it shows how to use different attributes including working with composite keys if this is what you are after.

Comment: hi I somehow manage this above issue, I'm getting another issue now which i have described here please check question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33596341/why-not-getting-foreign-key-property-into-scaffold-template-in-mvc-controller-an